# «Сердце Пармы» или «Сердце пармы»?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Роман Алексея Иванова — "Сердце **п**армы". Фильм по нему — "Сердце **П**армы".
Как правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно так, как у автора. Это закон непреложный, применимый и к книге, и к сценарию.

В книге автор недвусмысленно использует "парма" как имя нарицательное. 
К тому же это название "забито" в разного рода фестивали, конкурсы, туристические программы...

*Согласно словарю, парма на Северном Урале — это плосковершинные увалы и гряды, покрытые елово-пихтовыми лесами с густым моховым покровом[3]. Автор объяснял в письме своему редактору Олегу Дарку, что теперь такой тип леса мало где сохранился...*
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B
(Википедия).

К сожалению, прямая ссылка на словарь, использованный в Вики? уже не работает.
Но в нацкорпусе есть цитаты, подтверждающие использованием автором имени нарицательного.

Я не хочу вдаваться в вопрос о том, почему использовались разные подходы. Возможно просто недоразумение - или фильм отошел несколько от авторского понимания. Или от правила, что в названиях с заглавной пишется только первое слово. С последним вообще беда - под английский манер сейчас готовы писать с заглавной вообще все слова, включая предлоги.

Прочем в самой Вики есть упоминания и о том, что исходно фильм носил название, полностью соответствующее названию книги.

Answer (score -1):

Вообще-то правильно с большой буквы, так как это название территории.

Парма — одно из названий Перми Великой или Биармии — территорий на северо-западе Урала (от финно-угорского корня, обозначающего заросший лесом холм).

Здесь в названии романа "Парма" с большой буквы: http://ivanproduction.ru/intervyu/8.html

А на самой обложке книги название прописными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда вы взяли свое определение?!